# Gradle test parameter test suite

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm new with Gradle.

My problem:

Is it possible to switch between test suites in "Gradle test" depending on parameter?

Something like:

```
test {
useTestNG()
{
    suites 'src/test/resources/testng-'+input_parameter_as_string+'-Test.xml' 
    useDefaultListeners = true
}
```

My goal is to call: gradle test "input_parameter_as_string".

Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle documentation lists some ways to run specific test using system property: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:java_test . To run multiple correlated tests, you can try test group (both TestNG and Gradle supports): http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups .

If you insist to use your custom closure, you can always use project property. In build.gradle:

```
test {
useTestNG()
{
    suites 'src/test/resources/testng-' + project.ext.input_parameter_as_string  +'-Test.xml' 
    useDefaultListeners = true
}
```

and in command line:

```
gradle test -Pinput_parameter_as_string=testFoobar.
```

Answer (score -1):

Out of the box, Gradle supports running a single test:

`./gradlew test -Dtest.single=MyTestClassName`

Comment: This can be used only if you want to run single test class, and cannot be used to run specific TestNG xml suite!